# How to install a CAN port on PC (under Ubuntu)

Tags: can

We are using Ethernet as our current control bus and are considering switching to CAN. Our main computing unit is a PC under Ubuntu which needs to be fitted with a CAN port.

Anyone can recommend a PC to CAN hardware interface?

Any insight and experience feedback on using CAN on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For low cost, but well designed and well supported in linux,  I can recommend the  USB2CAN from 8Devices.

If you will be booting windows occasionally to set up industrial drives or sensors, or doing real-time,  stick with Peak or Kvasser.

If you will be adding a real-time kernel underneath Linux, check the driver list to confirm support for what you are buying.

CAN under linux with the socketCAN drivers works really nicely.

Comment: Really interesting! Your insight is invaluable, thanks!